# PHP unable to connect to SQL Server 2016

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I've searched all available threads on this question here and none of the answers are working for me.

I've installed (Windows 10 64-bit) Apache2.4 (64-bit), PHP 7.4.2 (64-bit) and SQL Server 2016 (64-bit).
I've updated php.ini to include

```
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```

which is from the package *php_sqlsrv-5.7.1preview-7.4-ts-vc15-x64* and when I run *php -m* to list all the modules *sqlsrv* is listed.

However, when I try to connect to the SQL server from a PHP file, it fails with an error message .

```
<?php  
 $serverName = "MYPC\\SQLINSTANCE"; 
 $uid = "sa";   
 $pwd = "thePassword";  
 $databaseName = "TesterDB"; 

 $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                     "Database"=>$databaseName); 

 /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */  
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  
 if( $conn )
 {
     echo "Connected";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Error";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
?>
```

error message:

> Login failed for user 'sa'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE]
>   => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] =>  4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "TesterDB"  requested
>   by the login. The login failed.

The login and password are correct, as are the PC and instance names.
What else could cause the connection failure? Some formatting issue? Some incompatibility?

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to your SQL Server using the `sa` account in the first place? A application should never be using the `sa` account. I would firstly suggest creating an login that only has the permissions that your application needs. Then, if that fails, consult the SQL Server's logs, which will tell you the exact reason why the authentication is failing (and include that in your question if you don't understand the error).

Comment: The sa account is always used to access this instance and database in the software we use. Don't ask me why, but this account works through osql, sql management studio etc. so the problem is not with the account. Also, using Windows Authentication fails in the same way in PHP (but works in osql etc.)

Comment: *"The sa account is always used to access this instance and database in the software we use."* Well, that needs to be changed; that';s a terrible idea, for *so* many reasons. if you're website, in this case, is ever compromised the person has access to **literally** do what ever they want. You really need to fix your security model ASAP.

Comment: I have no control over any of that and frankly it's of no interest to me. It's not a security issue but a programming one I need help with.
The SQL SERVER log does show an error, however:
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'TesterDB'. [CLIENT: <local machine>] If I run osql -S MYPC\SQLINSTANCE -U sa -P thePassword it connects instantly

Comment: *"frankly it's of no interest to me"* so it's not your problem if someone malicious uses *your* application do what ever they want, because *you* couldn't be bothered to get a permission limited service account? I mean no offience, but attitudes like that are why security breaches end up with so much data being leaked; because people that should care don't.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a database `TesterDB` on your instance, but I still suggest you fix those credentials. The attitude being expressed towards data security here is really poor. If you're effected by GDPR (which i doubt you're not) such poor practices would be seen as a big contributing factor, and as the application developer, you ***are*** responsible to ensuring you have the correct tools too; and the `sa` account is the completely wrong tool.

Comment: If you have no control over that, as someone maintaining an application which connects to the database, then you need to make contact with someone who _does_ have the ability change the login details, and request that it happens. If you're not interested in it, then I'm sorry to say but frankly that's just negligent, and I for one would not employ someone in my team who felt like that about the applications they are involved with.

Comment: P.S. the error you've mentioned in the comments is different to the one you've reported in the body of the question. So which one are you actually experiencing?

Comment: It's a day-old database, with one record, called 'test', on my test PC, with no exposure to the internet, no open ports, in my house, where I'm trying to teach myself PHP.

Comment: @ADyson the error in the body is from PHP, the one in the comments is from the SQL Server Log
You guys have helped me narrow down the issue to the database itself, rather than the SQL server, I'm pretty sure now. Thanks

Comment: *"I have no control over any of that"* -> *"on my test PC"* Then you *do* have control over it... It's your PC. Also, in the command line you gave us *"`osql -S MYPC\SQLINSTANCE -U sa -P thePassword`"* you didn't specify a database, where as in PHP you clearly are trying are, and that database appears to not exist. Or perhaps  it's a typhographcal error on it or it's (the database) is in single user and there's already a connection to it..

Comment: BTW to be clear, no-one is saying you shouldn't use `sa` for database administration tasks e.g. via SQL Management Studio, if you need to, but you should definitely never be using it for another application to log in.

Comment: @Larnu - you solved it, the db was in single user so the connection was being rejected from the PHP call

Answer (score -1):

Check the list:

1. Enable "Login by SQL Account" and "Windows Authentication" on MSSQL(properties/security)
2. Enable "SA Account Login" in the properties menu
3. Enable sql connection port on the firewall,(1433 default port) or disable firewall for only test
4. Enable remote connection to MSSQL if the connecting from other network
5. Troubleshoot the connect progress by profiler tools